# RSpec - Controller Specs with no corresponding views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

This is a simple issue for more advanced Rails developers, but I haven't been able to pin down an answer. I have two very basic controller specs that aren't passing. I don't have associated views (I'm adding/deleting products via `RailsAdmin`) but that shouldn't be an issue since in the controller I'm redirecting in each action.

Pertinent code is attached below. Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**products_controller_spec.rb**
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe ProductsController do
   describe 'GET #new' do
it "creates a new product" do
  get :new
    response.should be_success
  end
end

describe 'POST #create' do
  it "creates a new product and saves it" do
    expect{
  post :create, product: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product)
  }.to change(Product, :count).by(1)
end
  end
end
```

**controllers/products.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    redirect_to 'home'
  end

  def create
   @product = Product.create(params[:product])
   redirect_to 'home'
   end
 end
```

Error messages:

```
Failures:

  1) ProductsController GET #new creates a new product
     Failure/Error: response.should be_success
       expected success? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) ProductsController POST #create creates a new product and saves it
     Failure/Error: expect{
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.07747 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures
```

Comment: Do the `Product` model have any validation? could post both that model and the Factory_girl you have defined for it?

Comment: Thanks! Rather than post the model and validation, I'll just go ahead and let you know that that was the issue (typo in factories.rb file triggered a validation error). Hey, now I know what to look for in the future!

Comment: You should either use `create!` and handle any exceptions, or use `create` and check that the record is valid via `@product.valid?` or `@product.persisted?` or something, and handle validation failures.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that's a good tip to keep in mind. I'm relatively new to RSpec and feel that there are tons of good tips like you just mentioned that I'm currently unaware of, and I'm not sure where I'd pick them up. Then again, helpful people on Stack Overflow counts as a good source!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case `response.should be_success` only passes 
if a status code of `200` was returned. In your case, you are redirecting to `home` so 
  the status code will be between `300 - 399`. Change the first test to:

```
 response.should be_redirect
```

Not sure about the second one just yet.

Comment: Thanks! One down, one to go. I don't really "need" to redirect, but without the redirect line, I get an error saying that there is no corresponding view. If you have any thoughts on the matter feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Put this instead of the redirect if you don't really want to render a response.

```
head :ok
```

You should either use Product.create!

```
def create
  Product.create!(params[:product])
  head :ok
end
```

or check the return result of Product.create

```
def create
  if Product.create(params[:product])
    head :ok
  else
    head :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

or even better, return the errors in a response

```
def create
  product = Product.new(params[:product])

  if product.save
    head :ok
  else
    render json: product.errors
  end
end
```

Your current code is failing to create a Product, and the call to create is returning false but you are not checking it.  Using create! will throw an error for you if creation fails, otherwise you need to check the return value of create and handle the logic on the return value being true or false.  If you don't do this, you get silent failures, which are the worst kind of failures.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've switched to `head :ok` and I've added error rendering, but my code was still allowing me to create products via `RailsAdmin` as well as Rails console.

Comment: I assume that that would be expected behaviour.  The problem is that your test is not creating a model.  You want to see the errors on the model in the test code. It will probably show something obvious that you need to change in your FactoryGirl factory.